# How does HtmlTextWriter write to page?

Tags: c#, htmltextwriter

I'm trying to write HTML code into my ASPX file from my C# file. This is what I have so far, just to try to get it working before I actually starting putting in stuff that I want.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    writer.WriteBeginTag("p");
    writer.Write("THERE IS STUFF HERE");
    writer.WriteEndTag("p");
}
```

If my code up to this point is correct, then I assume I need some line of code that actually tells it to write, or something like that. However, I don't know what that is.

Also, if I get this working, what part of the page will it write to? Is there any way to tell it where to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *is* writing HTML. But it's writing it to your `StringWriter`, which is not what you had in mind.

Try writing it to `Response.Output` instead.

FYI, you would do  better taking that sort of code out of Page_Load and using a User Control instead.